# Can I compare a TextView's xml text with another string programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

If I set the text of a TextView in XML, like this:

```
    <TextView
        ...
        android:text="0" />
```

Can I compare that string in Java? Doing this:

```
    private void InitializeMethod() {
        A_1  = tv_1.getText().toString();
    }

    private void CheckAnsMethod() {
        if (A_1 == "0"){
            correctAns.start();
            }
        }else{
            wrongAns.start();
        }
    }
```

causes the sound 'wrongAns.mp3' to be played...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs to use the String class's equals() method:

```
 if ( "0".equals(A_1) )
```

`"0" == A_1` will compare the values of the references pointing to where the String objects are located.  In other words, it's comparing memory addresses when you really want to compare the characters in the strings.
The String class's `equals()` method will actually compare the strings character by character to check if they're equal.

Also, the reason I use `"0".equals(A_1)` instead of `A_1.equals("0")` is because if `A_1` is ever `null` for whatever reason, `"0".equals(A_1)` will not throw a `NullPointerException`.